# Getting value of C++ list iterator problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, list, iterator

I have code like this:

```
struct sWindowInfo {
    WNDPROC pPrevWndProc;
};
typedef std::list<sWindowInfo> windowsList;
```

And function, which returns pointer to iterator of first window-info struct in list:

```
windowsList::const_iterator* windowGet();
```

Code like this works fine:

```
if (windowsList::const_iterator* itr = windowGet())
{
    WNDPROC wndProc = (*itr)->pPrevWndProc;        
    return CallWindowProc(wndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

But if i try:

```
if (windowsList::const_iterator* itr = windowGet())
    return CallWindowProc((*itr)->pPrevWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

Runtime error occurs and i see strange values in debugger.
I don't understand, why? In my opinion this is identical code.

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to an iterator?

Comment: Show the implementation of `windowGet()`; you're probably returning the address of a temporary/local object.

Comment: Why not have list<WNDPROC> itself?

Comment: Of course struct has more fields, this is example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both implementations are wrong. You should not return pointers to iterator since it will be invalid after windowGet() call. 
It is the same thing as doing this:

```
int* getInt()
{
    int a = 10;
    return &a;
}

int* a = getInt();


int v = *a ; // v may be 10 or may be not
```

You may ask why first code is working? It is working just by luck: it happened that for that code compiler generates code that is not using the stack memory which was used by iterator. In second example compiler may generate a different code in which the iterator memory was used and changed.

Comment: My bad, thanks.. And can I return iterator itself? Or this is bad practice?

Comment: returning iterator by value is fine.

Comment: @valex : Returning iterators by value is _idiomatic_. Indeed, every standard library algorithm takes iterators by value.